# remove the dynamically created textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here I am created dynamic add and remove the text box using jquery,but I am struggle with removing of dynamic created text box.please help me remove dynamically of single box or row.

Remove the text box that is dynamically created using jquery with the onclick function.but I need remove the text box of which one have dynamic created button with remove option.
       The following code will remove all the dynamic created textbox,but I need to remove the textbox of single row.

```
<input type="button" id="buy_remove" name="del_item" value="Remove" class="bt" onClick="deleteRow_payment();"/>

    function deleteRow_payment() {
        $('DIV.product-item_payment').each(function(index, item){
                $(item).remove();
            add_payment();
        });

    }
```

Comment: Please provide html also

Comment: but my html is on another page..this  is what i need to do ..

Comment: just provide the full html of dynamic textbox

Comment: how this button with id `buy_remove` is related to dynamically created textbox?

Comment: @vijayP ie. id is not needed for that..

Comment: @navaskhan - I am assuming that there will be delete button for each and every dynamically created textbox. So I want to know how these buttons are related to their textboxes?

Comment: @vijayP it is related with div tag of div.product-item_payment..it is working but all the dynamic created textboxes are deleted.but i need of remove the corresponding text box with remove button.

Comment: @vijayP can you getting my point of thinking?

Comment: @navaskhan - what you mean by 'corresponding text box'? I don't see any relationship between button and textbox. If you want relationship between these 2 then I will suggest to have wrapper `div` around these pair OR button should have `data-textid="text001"` where `text001` is nothing but the corresponding textbox's `id`. By these way there will be some relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display` attribute in CSS something like this
`style="display:none"`
This way the DOM will ignore it

Comment: Doesn't seems like an answer. More like a comment.